# WhatsApp voice notes not playing

Tags: whatsapp, nokia-lumia-530

Whatsapp was updated on my phone and now I cannot play any voice notes. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, but the problem persists. I even tried turning my phone off, but still have the same issue. Can someone please help?

Comment: Sounds like a fault with the app, rather than Windows Phone. Have you contacted the developer?

Answer (score 3):

The app has been updated recently, resolved bugs with voice notes. The version **v2.12.226.0** solves this issue.

**Reference** : [WMPoweruser Article](http://wmpoweruser.com/whatsapp-updated-fix-voice-message-bug-caused-last-update/)

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? Which version exactly has fixed the voice note bug? Is there a link to an official post or changelog? Has the fix actually been confirmed?

Comment: @Indrek Edited the answer. It has been confirmed but I could not find a link to official post and there was no changelog in the store.

Comment: Thanks for editing and completing my answer. Totally didn't think about posting the version or a link to a related article.